# Регулярное выражение для получения числа из строки текста (перебор неограничен)

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Из строки `САМАРСКИЙ" — 25 отзывов` нужно получить количество, то есть число 25.

Делаю так:

```
preg_match_all('#(^\-\s)([0-9])(\sотзывов$)#is', $pattern, $matches);
```

возвращает:

```
array(4) {[0]=>array(0) {}[1]=>array(0) {}[2]=>array(0) {}[3]=>array(0) {}}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка?

Comment: Вам просто числа в тексте что ли нужно получить? `\d+` .

Comment: @СашаЧерных `#^(\-\s)(\d+)(\sотзывов)$#is` - не работает

Comment: `#\s+([0-9]+)\s+отзывов#i`

Comment: Тоже не работает

Comment: @Владимир ну как же не работает - https://www.regex101.com/r/oO7mH2/1

Comment: могу книжку подарить в электронном виде - кому то я сегодня её предлагал уже , на ozon 2000R стоит

Comment: `Тоже не работает` добавьте модификатор **u** `#\s+([0-9]+)\s+отзывов#iu`

Comment: И Ваш код не работает (

Comment: @LenovoID, спасибо большое! Владимир, числам в этой книге посвящена глава, начинающаяся со страницы 454.

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4AoB/1eebx7aSM  вот книга - прямая скачка - с облака майл ру

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так должно получиться:

```
\d+(?=\s+отзыв)
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте в той же консоли браузера выполнить:

```
/\s(\d+)\sотзыв/.exec('САМАРСКИЙ" — 25 отзывов')
```

Мне кажется, что ваша проблема - в кодировке. Например, вы написали скрипт в кодировке CP-1251, а сайт в кодировке UTF-8 (или наоборот), тогда и поиск регулярками, естественно, не работает:)
Попробуйте сначала [сконвертировать содержимое сайта](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php) в нужную вам кодировку.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно извлечь числа из строки, то можно и так:

**I**:

```
$str = 'САМАРСКИЙ" — 25 отзывов';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**II**:

```
$str = 'САМАРСКИЙ" — 25 отзывов';
$int = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo($int);
```

**III**:

```
$str = 'САМАРСКИЙ" — 25 отзывов';
$str = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

**UPD**
Ответ после уточнения:

```
$str = 'САМАРСКИЙ" — 25 отзывов';
preg_match_all('#.*\s+([0-9]+)\s+отзывов#u', $str, $matches);
print'<pre>';print_r($matches);print'</pre>';
```

Comment: Первый вариант почти подошёл, но он выбирает все цифры, а мне нужно именно из этой строки, так как я перебираю код всего сайта.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, что перебор не ограничен приведенной строкой.

Comment: Добавил ответ. Проблема, предположительна была в дефисе. Их, если не знаете, несколько видов.

Comment: фантастика, но не находит ничего. (

Comment: Код 1 в 1 выполняется и нет результата (1) или вы пытаетесь применить на свою ситуацию(2)? `1`. Что происходит на экране? Сделайте вывод ошибок, возможно  там что то прояснится. `2`. Добавьте в вопрос кусок текста от куда идет выборка побольше, чем больше, тем лучше.

Comment: код 1 - результат: выбирает все цифры на странице.
код 2, 3 не для моей задачи.
код UPD тоже не срабатывает к сожалению.

Comment: [epicfail] Вы запускали код под UDP 1в1?